# Apache multiple vhosts pointing to different dirs

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, vhosts

I have a local server running (apache) such that home.test points to  /www. I have a vhost pointing to /www/sites with the url sites.test. This works fine. Any folder inside /www/sites/ has the url xxx.sites.test. Now I want to add /www/dev such that any sub folders are linked to xxx.dev.test

```
<Directory "www/">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Virtualhost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "www/home/"
    ServerName home.test
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "www/sites/%1/_site/"
  ServerName sites.test
  ServerAlias *.test
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "www/dev/%1/_site"
  ServerName dev.test
  ServerAlias *.test
</Virtualhost>
```

Im getting something wrong here, I would expect the above https-vhost.conf to link /www/dev/xxx to xxx.dev.test but only home.test and xxx.sites.test work.

Comment: vhost 1 and 2 always seem to work regardless of what dir or domain they point to/define.

Comment: apachectl -D DUMP_VHOSTS confirms all 3 vhosts are active...

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! Basically a silly mistake. ServerAlias needs to be unique for each dir, so *.test becomes *.dir.test. Sorry everyone, as you where!